# Email Newsletter implementation using Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to create email newsletter tool  which include front end to manage content and to send the html as email.

What i'm trying to do is to maintain one angular template for UI and to send as email. This template also have some `IE` specific comments to make it work in outlook. Template can hold different html and style but data remains same.

This is what i started. https://plnkr.co/edit/NiYAopyCyFQyBK4aER5v?p=preview

1. Challenge i'm facing is how to compile html with data and render to the UI
2. How to get clean html without `ngif ngfor comments`to send it as an email.

[image]

### ********************** Update 9/21/2017 8pm *********************

Was able to solve first challenge. Updated plnkr

### ********************** Update 9/23/2017 8pm *********************

Was looking for proper way of `compiling  html string with data`. Had to go with  this approach with some limitation
https://github.com/tomalex0/compile-ng2-template

I'm looking for something similar to this https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-template in angular2.

Comment: Haven't figured out proper way of binding data to angular2 html string. Went ahead with this approach now and limited the usage of `*ngFor`

https://github.com/tomalex0/compile-ng2-template/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to make it work as i expected. Had to move certain logic to server side also.

Checkout plnkr and github

https://plnkr.co/edit/NiYAopyCyFQyBK4aER5v?p=preview

https://github.com/tomalex0/compile-ng2-template

```js
import { Component, Component,
    ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentRef,  NgModuleRef,ElementRef,
    Compiler, ComponentFactory, NgModule, ModuleWithComponentFactories, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 
  
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  container: ViewContainerRef;
  
 
    
  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private compiler: Compiler  
  ) { 
    
  }
  
  htmlstring : string;
  data = {
      title : "Newsletter",
      list : [{
         name : "One"
      },{
         name : "Two"
      }],
      enabled : true
  };
  
  templateArr = [{
    name : "t1",
    displayName : "Template1",
    html : `<div>
              <h1>Template 1</h1>
              <h2>{{data.title}}</h2>  <input name="title" type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.title" />
              <div>
                <li *ngFor="let listitem of data.list; let index = index">
                  List item {{listitem.name}}
                </li>
              </div>
              <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                  <div>Internet Explorer</div>
              <![endif]-->
              <div *ngIf="data.enabled">Enabled</div>
              <div *ngIf="!data.enabled">Not Enabled</div>
            </div>`
  },{
    name : "t2",
    displayName : "Template2",
    html : `<div>
              <h1>Template 2</h1>
              <h2>{{data.title}}</h2>  <input name="title" type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.title" />
              <div>
                <li *ngFor="let listitem of data.list; let index = index">
                  List item {{listitem.name}}
                </li>
              </div>
              <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                  <div>Internet Explorer</div>
              <![endif]-->
              <div *ngIf="data.enabled">Enabled</div>
              <div *ngIf="!data.enabled">Not Enabled</div>
            </div>`
  }]
        
  name = 'Angular Newsletter';
  
  loadTemplate (item) {
     console.log(item.html)
     let metadata = {
            selector: `runtime-component-dynamic`, 
            template: item.html
        };

        let factory = this.createComponentFactorySync(this.compiler, metadata);
        
        if (this.componentRef) {
            this.componentRef.destroy();
            this.componentRef = null;
        }
        this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
        this.componentRef.instance.data =  this.data;

  }
  
  private createComponentFactorySync(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component): ComponentFactory<any> {
    
      
      let decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(class { });
      
      @NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
      class RuntimeComponentModule { }

      compiler.clearCacheFor(decoratedCmp);
      let module: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any> = compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(RuntimeComponentModule);

      return module.componentFactories.find(f => f.componentType === decoratedCmp);
  }
  
  sendMail (){
    this.htmlstring = this.componentRef.location.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    this.htmlstring = this.htmlstring.replace(/<!--bindings[\s\S]*?(?:-->)/g, '');
   
  }
  
  
}




/*
Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```